# Django profile pic upload form saves picture in two folders

Tags: python, django, image-processing, django-models, django-forms

I've made a group picture upload in Django, but it saves **resized** picture in

> /media

folder and **original sized** picture in

> /media/group_pics

folder.

**models.py:**

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='group_pics/default-group.jpg', upload_to='group_pics/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def image_url(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if not ('default-group.jpg' in group.image.url) and group.image != self.image:
                group.image.delete()
        except: pass
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class GroupUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(max_length=150, allow_empty_file=False)
    x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    width = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['image']


    def save(self):
        group = super(GroupUpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.cleaned_data.get('x') != None:
            x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
            y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
            w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
            h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')
            image = Image.open(group.image)
            cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
            resized_image = cropped_image.resize((350, 350), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            resized_image.save(group.image.path)
        group.save()
        return group
```

When I do

```
print(group.image.path)
```

in forms.py under `def save():` it prints out *media\picture.jpg* while it should be *media\group_pics\picture.jpg*

and **views.py**

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        update_form = GroupUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=group)
        if update_form.is_valid():
            update_form.save()
```

---

**Expected behaviour:** It only saves **resized** picture to `/media/group_pics` folder

It does upload only to `/media/group_pics` if I use *admin panel*.

Where is my mistake that causes the double image save while uploading image through form?

Comment: If you upload an image through the Admin panel, does it behaves the same?

Comment: @revliscano No, if I upload through the admin panels it does upload only in `/media/group_pics folder`

Comment: Okay, so evidently the problem is in the form. Everything seems correct, though. The images that are being saved in /media are only the `resized_image` ones, right?

Comment: @revliscano Yeah, I just found that in `/media/group_pics` it saves the **original** picture not resized one. And in `/media` it saves the resized picture. I edited original post.

Comment: I'll make some tests in my local to see if I spot the error ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [generate_filename](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L295):

```
name = group.image.path
resized_image.save(group.image.generate_filename(group.image, name))
```

You may run into problems when updating the model or resaving the image. If that does happen, you probably could split `group.image.path` by `/` and take the last instance.

```
name = group.image.path.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: The `generate_filename` works only in Storage classes, how should I implement it if I have the save method inside ModelForm?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad link. I thought it was to the FileField, but it was the generic API. You can see the field itself will have a generate_filename method. Try using that. https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L295